# Why was Nimoy in the 2009 Star Trek movie and Shatner not?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

The story line of *Star Trek* (2009) explains that Spock was sent back trying to help Romulus but failed so he was forced to watch Vulcan get destroyed.

But, out-of-universe, why was Shatner not asked to appear in the movie?

Comment: Spock vaporizes rock....

Comment: What precisely are you looking for that my answer hasn't got? I've updated with Shatner's response as well as some other chat from the writers...

Comment: @N.Soong - The Jarjar Abrams quote below categorically states that he was asked, his own video states that he wasn't. Who to believe?

Comment: @Richard Both are probably right, it's just about alternate timelines and such.

Comment: @mario - Either that or JJA is some kind of Q. That would explain his weird obsession with lens flare...

Comment: @Richard - exactly my point.  I think the question ought to be changed, but the problem is *what* the question is specifically asking

Comment: He is used to being in the center of attention: Denny Craine

Comment: IMHO old Kirk needs to stay dead (and gone). Anyone who has been doing the show for nearly half a century and still calls the teleporters 'hover pads' obviously doesn't care so why should we (see the video in Richards answer before you deny that he does). As far as that goes, I'd say every captain since has done it better. He is a good actor but Patrick Stewart makes him look like an all out amateur. TOS has plenty of people left who actually gave a damn and haven't gotten much work outside of Star Trek over the years. Let them do the cameos and leave the heavy stuff for the kids.

Comment: @krowe - I find it sad that you can't tell that he's being ironic.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you didn't award the bounty...

Comment: I lost my phone and couldnt get on the site

Comment: @giacomocasanova - Fair enough

Comment: Im sorry for not awarding it

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the simplest terms, Nimoy was happy to accept a small cameo role whereas Shatner wasn't.

J.J. Abrams specifically addressed this issue (both in and out of universe) in an interview with [Sci-Fi Scanner](http://screenrant.com/shatners-star-trek-absence-explained-filmnerdjamie-3637/);

> *“It was very tricky. We actually had written a scene with him in it
>   that was a flashback kind of thing, but the truth is, it didn’t quite
>   feel right. **The bigger thing was that he was very vocal that he didn’t
>   want to do a cameo. We tried desperately to put him in the movie, but
>   he was making it very clear that he wanted the movie to focus on him
>   significantly**, which, frankly, he deserves.*
>
> *The truth is, the story
>   that we were telling required a certain adherence to the Trek canon
>   and consistency of storytelling. It’s funny — a lot of the people who
>   were proclaiming that he must be in this movie were the same people
>   saying it must adhere to canon. Well, his character died on screen.
>   Maybe a smarter group of filmmakers could have figured out how to
>   resolve that.”*

If it makes you happy, there were apparently [several attempts](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1611116/star-trek-writers-reveal-never-filmed-shatner-scene.jhtml) to write him in but the [writers claim](http://io9.com/5249752/the-shatner-scene-you-never-saw-in-abrams-star-trek) that there simply wasn't a good enough reason to skew the story purely in order to allow a two minute [continuity-porn](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ContinuityPorn) cameo:

> *The Shatner ending of “Star Trek” was abandoned for a
>   whole variety of reasons. “Whereas our elder Spock had a very organic
>   reason to be there, we didn’t have that same benefit with Kirk,”
>   Kurtzman explained. “**Because Kirk died in the movies — he died in
>   canon — it was very hard to come up with a way to bring him back in
>   the movie that didn’t feel contrived**.”*
>
> *“Ultimately, we decided internally that we were split,” Orci
>   remembered of the decision to abandon the Shatner ending. **“The
>   decision was that it wasn’t quite enough to justify wasting his
>   time.”***
>
> *Still, it’s pretty obvious where Orci fell in the internal debate. “It
>   was a nice voice-over. It was more than a scene,” he explained. “I
>   think it could have worked, personally.”*

---

William Shatner referenced this "cameo" in an interview on his website. **According to him, he was never asked to be in the film** but I suspect we can take this with a grain of salt...

Answer (score 14):

Romulus was destroyed in 2387, Kirk dies in 2371 (actually, even 78 years earlier, if we don't take Nexus in account). It would be really hard to explain his appearance.

Comment: LOL, nothing is really hard in the Star Trek universe.  In previous episodes and movies Kirk has already been duplicated by transporter accident, by changeling (twice!), as an android, and by mirror universe.  Kirk even *died* twice.  Trek is so full of magical technology, gods, demigods and reckless fools the only  wonder is that the Trek universe is as stable as it is.

Comment: Sorry, but the question asks for an out-of-universe explanation, so this doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @N.Soong agree. The question was changed, so now the answer is not very relevant.

Comment: @N.Soong: I would consider "being unable to come up with a good way to explain his appearance" is quite a decent oou explanation.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - They came up with an excellent way to put him into the film; He was going to appear in a (posthumous) holo-letter.

Comment: Thanks for that madfriend - I was unaware of that.